# error while building 2d game on windows phone 8

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

i was following [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/DirectX_on_Windows_Phone%3a_2D_Game_Example_using_DirectX_Toolkit) tutorial on 2D game dev using directTK on windows phone 8. but every time i run the example project i just get the error "Unhandled exception at 0x71144F23 (Msvcr110d.dll) in DirectXApp1.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued." i have checked to make sure the references and dependency are set up, which that are. and i've looked through the guide for more answers but to no avail.. any help but be much appreciated.

*update*

i also get this "The file invarg.c cannot be saved because it is write-protected.

You can either save the file in a different location or Microsoft Visual Studio can attempt to remove the write-protection and overwrite the file in its current location." when i try and save the project, im pretty sure this is linked to why it isn't running and giving the first error..

Comment: so far ive found nothing on the topic :/

Comment: Have you tried using the latest [DirectXTK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929)?